# Django sql-modifying onclick function

Tags: python, html, django

So I'm working on some Django app right now, which is basically kind of personal movie list. This app contains:

- Movie Model
- Custom User model

I want this app to display every user's lists as well as the main list, which contains every movie. In this last list I want to add in every row a custom button with onclick function, that adds this certain movie to logged in user list and saves it.

How and where do I make this function, to Add movie, which is in the same row, to a ManyToMany relationship with my user model? I tried to search how to do it, yet I didn't find a case, which contains onclick button actions, which modifies sql.

Here's my code:

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    countries = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class NormalUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)
```

Views.py

```
from .models import NormalUser, Movie


def index(request):
    movie_list = Movie.objects.order_by('-title')
    context = {
        'movie_list': movie_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'PTWList/index.html', context)

def userlist(request, pk):
    normal_user = get_object_or_404(NormalUser, pk=pk)
    current_user = request.user
    context = {'normal_user': normal_user,
               'current_user': current_user,
               'pk': pk}
    return render(request, 'PTWList/lists.html', context)

def movielist(request):
    movie_list = Movie.objects.all()
    current_user = request.user
    user_list = NormalUser.objects.all()
    context = {'movie_list': movie_list,
               'current_user': current_user,
               'user_list': user_list}
    return render(request, 'PTWList/movie_list.html', context)
```

movie_list.html

```
<h1>Movies</h1>
<ul>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% for movie in movie_list %}
    <li>{{ movie.title }} - {{ movie.director }} - <button 
type="button">Add</button></li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No movies yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for movie in movie_list %}
        <li>{{ movie.title }} - {{ movie.director }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No movies yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Forget about onclick, and certainly don't think about SQL. Do you know how to write a view that updates an attribute of a model?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: Ok, why not? Which part are you having trouble with? Have you done the tutorial? Your existing code shows that you know how to get an instance based on a URL parameter. What prevents you from modifying and saving that instance?

Comment: I've done tutorial, yet the one I did, didn't mention writing views that update an attribute of a model at all, so I basicall had no idea I could do it like this.
Then I'll just check how to do this and probably figure something out. Thanks a lot for mentioning this method.